# How to prove the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)$ converges?

Tags: calculus

How to prove this series is converging?
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)$$
Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Although someone has answered your question, it is getting downvotes. That's because you did not show any effort of your own before asking. That;s not the accepted way to go about asking for help on this site. In the future, please show your work - what you tried, even though you did not succeed.

Comment: Can you see now why it can't converge?

Comment: @YingYingTan Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$k^2\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)\sim4$$

thus it can't converge.

Comment: @AndrewLi For small $x$, $\sin(x) \approx x$...

Comment: @gimusi The general terms approach $4$ is sufficient.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes of course! You are absolutely right! I fix the comment, Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLi Simply observe that $$lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)}{\left(\frac2{k}\right)^2}=1$$ thus by definition $$\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)\sim \left(\frac2{k}\right)^2 \implies k^2\sin^2\left(\frac2k\right)\sim4$$ then refer to the necessary condition for convergence $a_k \to 0$.